# 0 found in empty array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to generate random numbers with the rand() function, and making sure they are not in the excArray.

If i do `print_r(array_values($excArray))` it returns `Array ( [0] => )` which means it is empty (right?)

But when i do `in_array($randInt, $excArray)`($randInt is = 0) or simply `echo in_array(0, $excArray);` it returns `1`

Here is my code:

```php
function generateCode($char, $int, $prefix, $len, $lenMin, $lenMax, $exclude, $array){
    do{
        $code = "";
        $i = 0;
        $excArray = explode(",", $exclude);
        echo in_array(0, $excArray);
        exit();
        while($i++ < $int){
            do {
                $randInt = rand(0,1);
                    echo $randInt;
            }while(in_array($randInt, $excArray));
            $code .= $randInt;
        }
```

So why does `echo in_array(0, $excArray)`; echo `1`?

Thanks!

Comment: No, array( 0 => ) means you have a value with an index of 0 it's just empty. But it will return true because it exists.

Comment: Why do you have so many parameters on your function if you don't use them? Also, from what I can see you're only generating rand numbers between 0 and 1. Your code seem too complex for such an easy task.

Comment: @PedroLobito I am using them. I just only posted the code i was having an issue with. The code is used to generate long uniqe codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array ( [0] => )` means there *one* item which prints as an empty string, probably `null` or `false` or... an empty string. Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to see more information about its actual type. From there you're probably encountering funky behaviour related to type casting when comparing numbers to strings... Either use `in_array(.., .., true)` for *strict* comparisons, or figure out what your empty item is in that array and avoid creating it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. The $exclude parameter comes directly from an empty input field. Using the strict comparison worked. I will mark this answer as correct as soon as it lets me.